# PHP array MySQL rows and columns?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a MySQL table that contains the following columns:

```
id : title : message : date
1  : blah  : blah    : 27/12/2012
```

And I have queried it and stored it in an array. How do I get the individual columns if a certain ID. For example, I want to get the row where ID = 1 and get the title, message etc. And then I want row 2 and row 3. How do I get the information out of an array. Like

```
$array[1]["date"]; ( I tried it and it never worked)
```

Comment: How are you storing it in an array? Can you add the code where you convert the result into a php array?

Comment: `And I have queried it and stored it in an array` most likely you are storing it with 0-indexed array

Comment: depends on how you have it stored in the array.

Comment: can you print your array so we can see what it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You basicly need to fetch the result as a associative array and loop through all the results. All your results will be in the form of

> array(
>       'id' => 1, 
>       'title' => 'blah',
>       'message' => 'blah',
>       'date' => '27/12/2012'
>   );

example for mysqli implementation of this: [Mysqli Fetch Assoc Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
while ($row = fetch_assoc($result)) { // use your favorite fetch method here
    $array[$row['id']] = $row;
}

echo $array[1]["date"]; // now will work (if you have such id)
```